# Lyapunov dimension

Tags: chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions, dimension-theory-analysis

I have a nonlinear differential equation system composed of 4 equations. I calculated Lyapunov's dimension of each of the states to be a little bit over 3 (say 3.11, 3.1, 3.13, 3.14). How can I interpret this result in the sense of chaos? What is the dimension's value telling me?

Thanks in advance.